# I'm trying to use this code to add items to the database, but it doesn't add them to database. How to use POST METHOD using PHP CODE with ajax?

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to use this code to add items to the database, but it doesn't add them to database. How to use POST METHOD using PHP CODE with ajax?

somebody help me ?

Here is my code :

```
      <?php
       $q1=$_POST["q1"];
       $q2=$_POST["q2"];
       $q3=$_POST["q3"];

      $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
      if (!$con)

     {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
     }

      mysql_select_db("stud", $con);

      $sql="INSERT INTO stud_info(IDno, LName, FName) VALUES ('$q1', '$q2', '$q3')";

      if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
      {
       die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
      }


     mysql_close($con);
     ?>
```

this is my ajax code :supposed to be cannot be null

```
     // JavaScript Document
     var xmlHttp;

     function showStud(id)
    { 
    xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
   if (xmlHttp==null)
    {
     alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
     return;
    }
     var url="getStud.php";
     url=url+"?q="+id;   
     xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
     xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true);
     xmlHttp.send(null);
    }

     function addStud(id, ln, fn)
    { 
    xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
    if (xmlHttp==null)
    {
    alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
    return;
    }
    var url="addStud.php";
    url=url+"?q1="+id+"&q2="+ln+"&q3="+fn;  
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
    xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
    }

    function editStud(id, ln, fn)
   { 
   xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
   if (xmlHttp==null)
   {
   alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
   return;
  }
   var url="editStud.php";
   url=url+"?q1="+id+"&q2="+ln+"&q3="+fn;
   xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
   xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true);
   xmlHttp.send(null);
   }

   function deleteStud(id)
   { 
   xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
   if (xmlHttp==null)
   {
   alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
   return;
   }
   var url="deleteStud.php";
   url=url+"?q="+id;   
   xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
   xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true);
   xmlHttp.send(null);
   }

   function stateChanged() 
   { 
   if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete")
   { 
   document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
   } 
   }

   function GetXmlHttpObject()
   {
    var xmlHttp=null;
   try
   {
   // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
   xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   catch (e)
   {
   //Internet Explorer
   try
    {
    xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
   catch (e)
   {
      xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
  }
   return xmlHttp;
  }
```

Comment: Not understand you question please post full code.

Comment: You're just assigning values to some variables here. I don't see anything that's even remotely related to inserting into a database.

Comment: combile the syntaxes to reduce big codes.. this is not an answer just a tip to inprove readability .. you can use $con = mysql_connect('localhost','root',''')or die(mysql_error()); and you can use mysql_query($sql,$con)or die(mysql_error()); and using mysql is no more, try using mysqli

Answer (score -1):

Add the jQuery library and check your console after integrating the code below.

Replace your `addStud(id, ln, fn)`:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

function addStud(id, ln, fn) { 
    var q1 = id;
    var q2 = ln;
    var q3 = ln;
    $.ajax({
        url: "addStud.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {q1: q1,q2:q2,q3:q3},
        success: function (data) {
               //Response here
        }
    });
}
```